# Instagram API Access Token

Tags: instagram

I am building a website for a client and we want to have an instagram slide show scroll at the bottom.  However it looks like they have a new API rule and are requiring access tokens which can only be acquired by logging into an account.  I was wondering if this means to see the pictures, visitors to the site will be required to log into their own instagram account in order to view our clients pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Nope... Log into your/client's account (receive access token). Search for photos you want and cache results. Display cached results for end user. That's it.